# Where is the servable index.html in this Angular2 / Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular, ecmascript-6

I have made minor modifications to [this Angular2 GitHub sample app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter) so that it uses Express instead of KOA.  But the problem is that FireFox gives the following error in the console when the root url of the app is loaded:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/vendor.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16ms]  
GET http://localhost:8080/boot.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16ms]
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/boot.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". localhost:8080
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' vendor.js:1:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' boot.js:1:0
GET http://localhost:35729/livereload.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 9ms]
GET http://localhost:35729/livereload [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 2ms]
```

It seems that the browser is not able to read the ES6 in the app.  In the sample app, Babel is used to compile the ES6 into a browser-readable form.  I have not changed the `gulpfile.js` or anything other than `router.js`, `server/index.js`, and `package.json`.  But somehow serving `index.html` does not give the client anything that it can read.

**What is the correct way to serve an ES6/Angular2 app from Express.js?  And what specific changes need to be made to the code below to resolve these console errors in the modified GitHub sample?**

Here are the two versions of the express route in [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js) that each generate the same error shown above:

Version 1:

```
'use strict';

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    //other routes omitted for brevity

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside / route!');
        res.sendfile(path.resolve('dist/client/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
    });
};
```

And version 2:

```
'use strict';

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    //other routes omitted for brevity

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside / route!');
        res.sendfile(path.resolve('client/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
    });
};
```

**Is serving `index.html` the problem?  Is there a better way to send the app from Express to the browser?**

The new [`server/index.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/index.js) is:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

// load the routes
require('./router')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

The only other file that changed is `package.json`, but I am omitting it here for brevity because it just lists new dependencies.  I can post it if requested by someone who is actually looking at this problem.

Comment: "Is serving index.html the problem?" — Well. Yes. You serve it for every single request. You should only serve it for `/` and give the browser whatever it asks for it it asks for something different.

Comment: @Quentin I tried serving both of the versions of `index.html` that are available in the app.  I figured one of the versions must be the one compiled into browser-readable form.  What code should I change to serve something the browser can read?

Comment: The error message is complaining that when you serve the JavaScript URLs … the browser is given HTML and when you serve the CSS URLs… the browser is given HTML. It isn't a problem with the version of the HTML document, it's a problem that you are serving it when the browser is asking for something else.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you.  I carefully examined the code in `vendor.js`, `boot.js`, and `boot.css`.  All three files contain the intended code for their file extensions.  The versions of the `*.js` files in the `dist` folder are compiled into what looks like simple JavaScript for the browser to read.  I also checked the FireFox developer tools, but was not able to gain access to the raw code in the versions of those files that got sent to the browser.  Since the server side files seem OK, is the problem then in the Express config?  What else can I do?

Comment: @Quentin I have a related question.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625483/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-with-angular2-and-express-js